# notepad++ How to swap two if and then statements

Tags: notepad++, swap, editing

So i have some code to reform (1000 lines) and i want to go from this

```
if $one=0 and $two=32 then $dist=1
if $one=0 and $two=15 then $dist=2
if $one=0 and $two=19 then $dist=3
```

to this

```
if $one=0 and $dist=1 then $two=32
if $one=0 and $dist=2 then $two=15
if $one=0 and $dist=3 then $two=19
in a few words swap both $two and its value with $dist and its value.
```

so far i tried this but its wrong

```
if ([^ ]+) and ([^]+) then ([^]+) 
/\3/ \2\1
```

can it happen with regular expressions of notepad++ ? cheers

Comment: You may use replace shortcut (Ctrl+H) twice to replace the both words.

Comment: There is already an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45401626/372239

Answer (score 0):

#### Swap both $two and its value with $dist and its value

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^if (.*?) and (.*?) then (.*?)$`
- Set "Replace with" to `if \1 and \3 then \2`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
if $one=0 and $two=32 then $dist=1
if $one=0 and $two=15 then $dist=2
if $one=0 and $two=19 then $dist=3
```

After:

```
if $one=0 and $dist=1 then $two=32
if $one=0 and $dist=2 then $two=15
if $one=0 and $dist=3 then $two=19
```

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)